# prove if p is a prime having the form 4k+3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

Hi I was having a little trouble with this question that prove if p is a prime having the form $4k+3$, and if $m$ is the number of quadratic residues less than $p/2$,

then $$1.3.5...(p-2)≡(-1)^{m+k+1}\pmod p$$,

and$$2.4.6...(p-1)≡(-1)^{m+k}\pmod p$$

I just dont understand the question.

Comment: What is it about the question that you do not understand? Is there any term that you do not know the meaning of? Or is it rather that you don't know where to begin solving it? For starters, have you confirmed it in cases like $p=3,7,11$?

Comment: to begin solving it, its a completely new area for in number theory and the  sheet I found didn't include any notes to help.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?